# Values are being passed correctly however selection statements do not work properly

Tags: python, pygame, selection

I've been recently trying to code a quick game which involves binary to hex conversion. I've set up some of the basic structure of the code but I've stumbled upon a problem: My selection statement in the game's entry point doesn't work as intended even though the values should be passed on correctly

**What I've tried:**

- I tried "debugging" the program by adding print statements in between the function and statements, eg:

```py
     if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
        print('enter')
        print(key_value)
        key_value = 1
        print(key_value)
```

The values when printed are correct, which are used in the game's while loop point:

```py
    while running:

        if EventHandler.get_key_pressed() == 1:
            print('1')

        elif EventHandler.get_key_pressed() == 2:
            print('2')
```

- Changed the conditions of the statement, still got the same results eg:

```py
     elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
            print('enter')
            key_value = 2

         elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            print('space')
            key_value = 1
```

- Changed the get_key_pressed() function to a non-static one, still had the same results.
- Went back to basic python tutorials to make sure my indentation and structuring/usage of selection statements are correct.

From my observations, only the first if statement after the while loop in works, however I'm not sure as to why that happens when I think I formatted my code properly.

**Code:**
**main.py**

```py
import pygame
from Include.src.event_handler import EventHandler
    # other imports go here, not related to problem.

    # Global Variables
    running = True

    # Object creations, not really related as well
    game = Game()  # initialise pygame, settings and assets
    screen = game.get_screen()  # get screen bounds/object

    while running:

        if EventHandler.get_key_pressed() == 1: # Issue here
            print('1')

        elif EventHandler.get_key_pressed() == 2:
            print('2')


        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
```

**event_handler.py**

```py
    import pygame


    class EventHandler:
        @staticmethod
        def get_key_pressed():
            key_value = 0

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    print('Thanks for debugging me or playing idk')
                    pygame.quit()

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
                        print('enter')
                        key_value = 1

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        print('space')
                        key_value = 2

            return key_value
```

**Expected output**

Person presses space, *space and 2 is printed.*
Person presses enter, *enter and 1 is printed.*

**Actual output**

Space pressed, *only space is outputted.*
Enter pressed, *both enter and 1 is outputted.*

Thank you so much!

Comment: You call `get_key_pressed()`, and compare its return value to 1.  If not equal, you *call `get_key_pressed()` again*, throwing away the original return value, and compare this *new* value (which is always 0, because the keypress event has already been handled) to 2.

Comment: @jasonharper hmm, I see. But using a return value (eg 1, 2) instead of a variable (key_value) still leads to the same result? Or did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking back to this post, I've found the answer:

As @jasonharper said, the value was being thrown since the function was being called again

```py
     while running:
        e = EventHandler.get_key_pressed() # make it constant
        if e == 1:
            print('1')

        elif e == 2:
            print('2')
```